# Function called with setTimeout still runs instantly

Tags: javascript, html

I need to call a Javascript function from my HTML twice but I need a delay between the two.  When I run the code below it uploads both files nearly instantly even though there should be a full minute delay.  Any idea what I'm missing here?

```
      sendFileToDrive(allFiles1[0]);
      setTimeout(sendFileToDrive(allFiles2[0]),60000);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass a function, not execute one.

```
 setTimeout(() => sendFileToDrive(allFiles2[0]), 60000);
```

Now the function that you passed to `setTimeout` will be executed after one minute, and will execute the call to `setFileToDrive`.

---

The above uses an arrow function. Here's one with traditional syntax.

```
 setTimeout(function () { sendFileToDrive(allFiles2[0]) }, 60000);
```

---

You could also use `.bind()`.

```
setTimeout(sendFileToDrive.bind(this, allFiles2[0]), 60000);
```

This assumes that the `0` index of `allFiles2` already contains the data you need to pass.